# Does this south bridge datasheet show everything?

Tags: southbridge

I am looking at the VT82C686A south bridge, does this datasheet have enough info on it to do something like write a custom BIOS (I'm trying to set up myself a machine that runs not proprietary stuff, fully :P) for any motherboard that uses this?
ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/manuals/via/VT82C686A%20SB%20datasheet%20rev%201.8.pdf
Just found this as one of the first links when googling it

Comment: Looks pretty complete. I had this southbridge on my old PC; there's also a Linux kernel driver for it, so you can look at the source if you need to. Also note that the successor to the 686A, the 686B, had a [hardware bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIA_chipsets#Hardware_bugs), so look closely.